# How to extract XML data stored in amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-athena

I was provided a table in Amazon Athena and one of the columns contains XML data. Probably this is not the best way to go, but I need to work with what I have.

From what I read, there is no native support to extract data out of those XMLs (like using XPATH or so). Is there a way to compose a query so it parses the XML and extracts some data that is stored within it?

Comment: athena uses `presto` on the backend and currently there is no functionality to parse native `xml` in `presto` aside from using regular expressions which sounds like a nightmare

Comment: In the future this might be possible using user defined functions. Currently these are not supported: https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Flexter tool from https://xmlconverter.sonra.io/ to convert your column to TSV file and use Athena queries on the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I made this npm cli to build a json using pipes

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gbalbuena/xmltojson-cli

once you get the json you could use jq to extract and transform